# Android - Activity não mostra nenhum componente xml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Estou começando com o Xamarin studio e por nem mostra o "hello world"

[image: Print retirado]

Comment: Bem vindo, edite a pergunta e coloque o código.